# resolving a request for member ... which is of non-class type

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mingw-w64

I wanted to know why the following code compiles in Visual Studio but gives a compilation error in Mingw GCC during porting. This is my first time coming in contact with `__m128` type but from [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayeb3ayc(v=vs.90).aspx) link here it states

```
You should not access the __m128 fields directly. You can, however, see these types in the debugger. A variable of type __m128 maps to the XMM[0-7] registers.
```

The code base is very old and this type is being used as

```
Matrix m;
__m128  b0 = _mm_set_ps(b[0][0], b[1][0], b[2][0], 0);
__m128  b1 = _mm_set_ps(b[0][2], b[1][3], b[2][4], 0);

__m128  a00 = _mm_load1_ps(&a[0][0]);
__m128  a10 = _mm_load1_ps(&a[1][0]);
__m128  r1a = _mm_mul_ps(a00, b0);
__m128  r1b = _mm_mul_ps(a10, b1);
__m128  r1 = _mm_add_ps(r1a, r1b);

m[0][0] = r1.m128_f32[3];
```

The error that I get is

```
 error: request for member 'm128_f32' in 'r1', which is of non-class type '__m128 {aka __vector(4) float}'
  m[0][0] = r1.m128_f32[3];
```

I tried looking up this error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877523/error-request-for-member-in-which-is-of-non-class-type) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16364116/request-for-member-which-is-of-non-class-type) however I believe they do not apply to my case as they dealt with the C++ most vexing parse issue.
Any suggestions on how I could resolve this issue would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

GCC doesn't use a union for these types as VS does, the types are handled as built-in types. You can directly index a __m128, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19582893/accessing-m128-fields-across-compilers).
This introduces a portability problem, of course. In my projects I use a wrapping class with a union and overloaded operator[] but the generated code is sub-optimal.